# replace string between xml elements with variable name spaces

Tags: java, regex

Using Java, String and replaceAll I have to replace values of elements that may come with different name spaces:

from

```
<tns:p>to be replaced</tns:p> 
<sss:p>to be replaced</sss:p>
```

to

```
<tns:p>replaced</tns:p> 
<sss:p>replaced</sss:p>
```

Could you please, help to find regular expression for this replace?

P.S. The elements may appear more than once in a given string:

```
<tns:p>to be replaced</tns:p>
<tns:w>not to be replaced</tns:w>
<tns:p>to be replaced</tns:p>
```

I have a problem with variable name spaces in front of elements.
Without them I'd do like this:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=<p>)(.*?)(?=</p)", "replacement")
```

Comment: And have you tried anything? Some code?

Comment: As with nearly every question in this tag, your description leaves quite a bit of ambiguity. Are you wanting to only retain the final word in the element? E.g. would `<foo>tell us more</foo>` become `<foo>more</foo>`?

Comment: It's reasonably easy to do, but what is it about the problem that you are having difficulty with?

Comment: Why would you want to use a regex rather than an XML API? That's almost *always* the wrong decision.

Comment: @Duncan I think he's given unfortunate examples for his strings: he wants `<foo>x</foo>` to become `<foo>y</foo>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: @Bohemian Ah, that sounds plausible. One day I'll write my ranting blog post about how to (not) specify a regex question and just start linking to that each time.

Comment: @JonSkeet because (in java at least) it's easier, uses way less code, and is a *lot* faster to use regex - all by a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Bohemian: And far harder to get *right*. Personally I'd rather have robust code that might be a bit slower than fast code which will fail as soon as it has slightly unusual (but valid) input.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure, code that works beats buggy/brittle code every time and regex doesn't lend itself to "parsing" xml, but in this case it's a problem in which the xml context is irrelevant: regex can tackle this easily - it's essentially a string replacement problem with a simple back-reference in the regex to be safe (you could even omit the back-reference if you knew the input was reliably well formed).

Comment: I'll look forward to ensuring that the answer works in the face of CDATA etc...

Comment: @JonSkeet OK - you got me with CDATA, but that seems to be out of scope (the CDATA would have to firstly exist and secondly itself contain a closing tag... unlikely) and over-engineering is bad too

Comment: Each to their own. Whenever I want to manipulate XML, I use an XML API. It's as simple as that for me. Admittedly I'd usually use LINQ to XML and C#, which is much nicer than any Java XML API I've used...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that look-behinds can't have variable lengths, but if your input is well formed (that is tags are closed with matching tags), and you text to be replaced isn't a CDATA element that itself contains the closing tag (seems unlikely), this will work:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[:<]p>)[^<]*(?=</(\\w+:)?p>)", "replacement");
```

This regex makes the replacement whether or not there's a namespace.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "<p>to be replaced</p><tns:p>to be replaced</tns:p><tns:w>not to be replaced</tns:w><tns:p>to be replaced</tns:p>";
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[:<]p>)[^<]*(?=</(\\w+:)?p>)", "replacement");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

replacement

replacementnot to be replacedreplacement

If you input is *not* well formed and simple, ie the closing tag namespace may *not* be the same, you can do it by capturing the namespace, using a back-reference to assert it's the same in the closing tag, and putting it back in the replacement:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(<(\\w+:)?p>)[^<]*(?=</(\\2)p>)", "$1replacement");
```

The namespace is still optional, but now the namespace in the closing tag must match that of the opening tag.

Comment: No worries. There's another option I just added in case you want to be stricter with the namespace matching.

Comment: Sorry, it worked for you because you separated elements with \n (new line).

Comment: For this case it won't work String str = "<tns:p>this it to be replaced</tns:p><tns:w>not to be replaced</tns:w><tns:p>this it to be replaced</tns:p>";

Comment: Fixed: The reluctant quantifier wan't reluctant enough - I changed it to be "not a `<` char". Try the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds in java regex don't support repitive operators, So unfortunatly this is **not** possible with just one `String#replaceAll(String, String)`